# Customize slider

Tags: wpf, slider, controltemplate

I need to customize the appearance of the slider in order to use it in touchscreen mode. The slider's thumb needs to be 60 - 80 px high.
From all the suggestions around I understand that I will have to modify the slider's control template. 
What I was wondering: where can I get the slider's control template? I want the slider to look the same as it does originally, just with a bigger thumb.

Comment: in Expression blend  you can edit a copy of the original template , it's a good place to start for all control template modifications.

or you can search for the original template on the web 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278073(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Expression blend you can edit a copy of the original template , it's a good place to start for all control template modifications.

or you can search for the original template on the web  :

[Slider Tempalte and Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But I do not have Expression Blend. Are there any other tools I could use?

Comment: I used the style for the slider from your link and resized the thumb. It looks good, but the slider does not move anymore. (I just copied the style into my resource file).

Comment: do you have expression blend ?

Comment: No. See my earlier comment.

Comment: StyleSnooper was what I was looking for. Got the entire Template for the Slider from it and modified it. And used Kaxaml to check my modifications.

Comment: @tabina nice , i never hard of that util before ill dl it as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Blend to edit a Template.

Right click your slider in VS Designer `Edit Template -> Edit a copy...`, go ahead and play with it. If you're familiar with XAML it should not take too long for you to get it right.

Just remember that WPF/WP is all about DPI independence. If you fix a Height and Width at a certain value, in some screens the control may look small/large!